# How can I change column width on printed reports

Tags: civireport

How do I change the width of columns on printed reports. Some columns are too wide and some are too narrow.

Answer (score 0):

Depends whether its a one off report or something that you want to use regularly or for others to use without having to configure. The way I get reports looking how I want them is to export as CSV and then use Excel to set up the layout.

Comment: I tried export as CSV to Excel. Problem is that users must save the exported file with a specific name, then must open the Excel file that actually contains the printed format. Excel is limited in formatting compared to Access. It would be nive if CiviCRM would allow formatting then just click and print.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Administer > Communications > Message Templates > System Workflow Messages > Pick the receipt that you need to edit. 
Scroll down to the HTML Format box and edit the layout to your liking. Then click save at the bottom.

Comment: Err... that changes an email receipt, not a report doesn't it.

Comment: Opps, yes, I misread your question